# test a java method in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Let's say I found this piece of code and I want to test it in Netbeans before I incorporate it:

```
ArrayList list; 
for(String s: list)
{
    Integer c = stringsCount.get(s);
    if(c == null) c = new Integer(0);
    c++;
    stringsCount.put(s,c);
}
```

Is there a way to test the above code in Netbeans without having to create a temp class with a main? I believe there is a way in Eclipse but I am looking for a way in Netbeans. Thank you.

Comment: So... you want to magically run some code with magical parameters that cover all branches?

Comment: You'll have to incorporate that into some sort of test class. You can't just run some random code.

Comment: What do you want to test about it?  Some fruitful first research would be looking into Junit and how to write test cases, and then looking into Junit integration with your IDE.

Comment: Logan, I don't recall the exact name of the option in eclipse but it is like a scratch pad that you add to your project. You can type some code and test it. I take it from your answer that such feature does not exist in netbeans.

Comment: Every java program needs entry point `main method ` to execute

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to test the above code in Netbeans without having to create a temp class with a main?

As far as I know, you can't do that. Your program needs an ***entry point***. The main method is supposed to be your program's entry point.

If you are reluctant to always create a new class. You can always have a class for testing. Just replace the old codes with new testing codes whenever you need it.

---

P.S: I don't think it can be done in Eclipse as well.